# How to implement an optional property?

Tags: python

I want to set up a property only if requested explicitly. As this property will involve extra computation time, I want it initialized with `None` and only initializing if a calling function requests to do so.

For example:

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, filename, content):
         self.filename = filename
         self.content = content
         self.hash = None or self.get_hash()

    def get_hash():
          '''do some hashing there'''
```

I have seen some property of that kind but don't know how this could work trigger the function by calling:

```
my_file = File('text.txt', 'Hello there')
my_file.hash
```

Comment: Check out the [property decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) and Hettinger's [Beyond Pep8 talk](https://youtu.be/wf-BqAjZb8M) for how to use it. He goes over exactly this problem.

Comment: Thank you, i will definitely check it, just read Fluent Python but i don't get everything, the metaprogramming part was too much for somebody who did too few POO with python, i will check the talk later. =)

Comment: Just quick question, the @property need to be bind to a function with the same name as the attribute right?

Comment: Raymond Hettinger also has a very good explanation of Properties in his _Descriptor HowTo Guide_ https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html#properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By providing `.hash` with a property getter, you can create exactly the behaviour you want. The actual value of `hash` will be 'hidden' as `._hash` which is a common practice in Python:

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, filename, content):
         self.filename = filename
         self.content = content
         self._hash = None

    @property
    def hash(self):
          if self._hash is None:
              # do some hashing here
              self._hash = 'some hash'
          return self._hash


f = File('myfile', 'some content')
print(f.hash)
```

Of course, you could also have other conditions when you need the hash to be recalculated, it doesn't have to be `if self._hash is None`. And you could also just reset the hash when it needs to be recalculated. For example, perhaps your hash changes when `.content` changes:

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, filename, content):
         self.filename = filename
         self._content = content
         self._hash = None

    @property
    def hash(self):
          if self._hash is None:
              # do some hashing here
              self._hash = f'some hash based on {self._content}'
          return self._hash


    @property
    def content(self):
          return self.content

    @content.setter
    def content(self, value):
          self._content = value
          self._hash = None


f = File('myfile', 'some content')
print(f.hash)
f.content = 'changed content'
print(f.hash)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you made it pretty explicit. I don't need the second part right know, but that's feeling a good-to-know thing

Answer (score 3):

Try passing it as a parameter while creating the Object.

Check if the below code is suitable for you:

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, filename, content, request_hash=False):
         self.filename = filename
         self.content = content
         self.hash = self.get_hash() if request_hash else None

    def get_hash():
          '''do some hashing there'''
```

---

```
my_file = File('text.txt', 'Hello there') #No Hash is generated
my_file = File('text.txt', 'Hello there', True) #Hash will be generated
```

Comment: You could also use a ternary:  `self.hash = self.get_hash() if request_hash else None`

Comment: @Alexander, Yes. Ternary Operator can also be used. It looks better. I have edited my answer. Thanks!